# PHP: mysql_fetch_array exclude duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I got a simple line of code, that fetch the sequel database and populate a category list, these category strings come by a product table, so many product row produce duplicate category entries.

```
$cat_result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM products");
while ($cat_row = mysqli_fetch_array($cat_result, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
    if($cat_row['4'] != NULL) { 
        print '<li><a href="/category/'. $cat_row['4'] .'">'. $cat_row['4'] .'</a></li>'; 
    }
}
```

The current output is like this:

- Category1
- Category1
- Category2
- Category2

So how I can suppress duplicate entry and got something like this?

- Category1
- Category2

Thanks for your help!

Comment: DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- , see you again! So I must to do "SELECT * FROM product GROUP BY category" where I must to use DISTINCT?

Comment: `$cat_result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM products"); or $cat_result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY name");`

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT WhatEverTheColumnIsCalled FROM products` specially as you only use one column, dont retrieve more than you use and you will find that it run quicker as well

Comment: Ciao Andrea! si, and `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM TABLE` as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html - *come stai?*

Comment: Grazie Mille @Fred-ii-, Working as expected!

Comment: prego Andrea. would you like me to submit an answer?

Comment: If you submit the answer i can set to correctly replied!

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard i'm going to follow the hint!

Comment: è fatto Andrea. a presto!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested:

You can use either a DISTINCT in SELECT and/or a GROUP BY

I.e.:

`SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM TABLE GROUP BY col_x`

as per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

which will avoid duplicates in your query.

Additionally, a `WHERE` clause could also be useful (later on).

I.e.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM TABLE WHERE col_x = 'y' GROUP BY col_x
```

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by everyone above `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` both can solve your problem, so you can do like below:-

Suppose the column name is `category` then:-

```
$cat_result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM products"); 

OR 

$cat_result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY category");
```

**Note:- you can choose n number of different column in `DISTINCT` too as suggested by others. Thanks.**